# Error while writing the strings having suqare brackets to postgresql table using psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to write a dataframe to a postgres table and i am using psycopg2 for it. One of the column in my dataframe has square brackets values in it as shown below,

```
['3709464835']
['3709455144', '3709455145']
```

there are around 28 columns in the dataframe so i am just writing a short version of my SQL query below,

```
"""INSERT into table_abcd(customer_name, order_no)values('%s',%s)""" %(name,order)
```

i am getting the error for order variable as...

```
Error: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 8:             ['3709462416', '3709462448']
```

i even tried '%s' for order variable but it gives the following error..

```
Error: syntax error at or near "3709462416"
LINE 8:             '['3709462416', '3709462448']'
```

Please help.

Comment: what is the data type of `customer_name and order_no`?

Comment: both are strings

Comment: then in your `INSERT` statement you are using two different ways `'%s'` `%s`

Comment: yes...i have tried for both %s and '%s' for order but i was getting error in both... i have mentioned both the errors above

Comment: The data items should go in the second parameter of `Cursor.execute` so they are properly converted and escaped. You should not use regular string formatting with SQL. The snippet you're posting is also extremely unfortunate as it's missing most of the relevant information, not runnable, not reproducible, and unclear whether your items are strings which look like list literals, or actual lists.